# iPhone: " 'class_name' may not respond to methd_name" and "Unrecognized selector" Errors

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimage, selector

I have written an application in which I want to convert a .jpg image to .bmp format but I it fails with the error:

> class_name' may not respond to
>   methd_name".

My code is following :

```
#import "CalculateRGBViewController.h"

@implementation CalculateRGBViewController

@synthesize skinImage;
@synthesize lblRedColor,btn,img;
struct pixel {
    unsigned char r, g, b,a;
};


-(IBAction)btnClick:(id) sender{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

}
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    skinImage.  image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

}

+(void)calculateRGB:(UIImage *)skinImage    {

    struct pixel *pixels = (struct pixel *) calloc(1, skinImage.size.width * skinImage.size.height * sizeof(struct pixel));
    if (pixels != nil)
    {
        // Create a new bitmap

        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                     (void*) pixels,
                                                     skinImage.size.width,
                                                     skinImage.size.height,
                                                     8,
                                                     skinImage.size.width * 4,
                                                     CGImageGetColorSpace(skinImage.CGImage),
                                                     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
                                                     );
    NSLog( @"Pixel data one red (%i)", context);        
}

}
-(IBAction)btnCalRGB:(id) sender
{
    [self calculateRGB];

}

The shown me following code. 
-(IBAction)btnCalRGB:(id) sender
{
    [self calculateRGB];


}
```

Warning: CalculateRGBController may not respond to calculateRGB in btnCalRGB button function.

### Edit01:

I have also implemented in my code but it again showing same warning.

```
[self calculateRGB:anUIImage]; 
-(IBAction)btnCalRGB:(id) sender;
```

but it again showing same warning. When the button above is pressed, the program throws and exception.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[UIImage skinImage]: unrecognized selector sent to
```

Comment: Some additional details will help. Post the exact exception description (including the class and method names), write the problematic line in the code. Fix your post - the code looks awful (each line of code in the post should start with at least 4 spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the method wrong. You must call it like this;

```
[self calculateRGB:anUIImage];
```

Your method takes an UIImage as an argument, so you must send it when you call the method. You should also add

```
+(void)calculateRGB:(UIImage *)skinImage;
```

to your .h file

Use this

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
```

instead of this

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
```

and you can write

```
skinImage.image = image;
```

Comment: Hi EEE, the following line i also implementing in my code but it again showing same warning.
[self calculateRGB:anUIImage];

-(IBAction)btnCalRGB:(id) sender 
on above button the program throwing exception.
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[UIImage skinImage]: unrecognized selector sent to............
Thanks

Comment: You call the method like this [self calculateRGB:anUIImage] or like this [self calculateRGB:skinImage.image]? and see the update in my answer.

Comment: EEE, which steps i should have follow for to get number of RGB pixel counting from iphone camera captured image?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to get rid of the error:

```
+(void)calculateRGB:(UIImage *)skinImage
```

Should be

```
- (void)calculateRGB:(UIImage *)skinImage
```

The `+` is for **class** methods, you're about to call this on **instances** (this is we you need to use the `-`). So the error is because you try to call the instance method but there is no instance method named `calculateRGB:`.

The method wants an `UIImage` to do it's calculation on. This means you should call it (like EEE told you already):

```
[self calculateRGB:anImage];
```

`anImage` would be an `UIImage` instance you provide. This could be the `skinImage` that you're already using in the implementation, as shown in your code.

Apart from this, I would recommend **not** to use an `UIViewController` subclass for stuff like calculating the RGB values of an image. You should probably use a category of `UIImage` for this.

Comment: ChriB, Which class i have to be use instead of UIViewController.

Comment: ChriB, do u have some idea regarding to find out numbers of RGB(red,green,blue) pixels counting from iphone camera captured image or which setps of image processing should i have follow to get those pixels?